# Searching a number in a binary search tree. If it doesn't exist, find the the biggest number smaller than it

Tags: algorithm, find, binary-search-tree

Say you have a balanced binary search tree (say AVL tree) with n numbers.

You need an algorithm that looks for a given number x, but if it doesn't find it,
returns the largest number that is smaller than x.

For the sake of the question do it without inserting x and then removing it, and the solution should be O(log(n)).

Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting problem. What did you do to try and solve it?

Comment: Sure thing, sir. A cup of tea while we do your work?

Comment: It's not work actually, it was a part of a test. Thought it was an interesting problem and wanted some help with it. In the test you could insert x and then remove it, trying to think if it's possible without doing that

Comment: The direction I thought in is look for x, if you didn't find it go to where it would be (like the insert function of an AVL tree) and try to do a predecessor like action from there. Not entirely clear about it though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is about finding the Inorder Predecessor of a (virtually) inserted node. I will first explain what an Inorder Predecessor is and then explain how we can find the Inorder Predecessor in a BST.

Before we can talk about the Inorder Predecessor, we must first be familiar with Inorder Traversal of a Binary Search Tree.
An Inorder traversal is an algorithm to visit all the nodes of a Binary Search Tree in a specific order as outlined in the recursive algorithm below:

```
Inorder(Node S)
  Inorder(left child of S)
  print S
  Inorder(right child of S)
```

In plain words, we recursively print the left tree, then the center node, and then the right subtree.

The algorithm is quite simple yet elegant in that when it prints the keys in this order, owing to the ordering of keys in the structure of a BST, we would be getting a special sequence of keys. What is that special sequence? Let's trace the algorithm for a BST and check that.

Let's consider the BST shown below:

[image]

Here, let's trace our algorithm, first we start the algorithm at the root(node with value 20), then as the algorithm says we recursively call the same function for the left subtree, which is the subtree rooted at node 8, and again we call for the left subtree of 8, which is the node 4. At this point 4 has no left subtree, so we print the key 4. Since 4 has no right subtree, we are done for the subtree rooted at node 4, and we backtrack to the node 8. Now we print the node 8. Then we call the recursive function for the right subtree of node 8, and following the algorithm step by step, you will realize that the sequence printed is: 4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22

What is this sequence? It's just the sorted sequence of the keys.

How did this happen? Well, it's just the way BST nodes are structured: BST has a special property which is that for each node S, all keys to the left of the node S are lesser than S and all nodes to the right of S are greater than S.

In other words, the Inorder traversal just neatly prints out the keys of a Binary Search Tree in the sorted order.

Okay, now that we understand the recursive algorithm that prints the Inorder Traversal of a BST, we re-focus on our task of finding the node which would be the the largest node that is smaller than our target node. What is this node? It's just the node which would be printed just before our virtually inserted node in the Inorder traversal of the BST. This is called the Inorder Predecessor.

Let's look back at our BST and understand what an Inorder Predecessor is.

[image]

Here what is the Inorder Predecessor of 12? What do we do? We know that the Inorder Predecessor of a node is the node which was printed just before this node was printed in the Inorder traversal. Which node can this be? To answer this, we must visualize the exact point in time at which our node 12 would be printed. Clearly for something to be printed before a specific node by our Inorder traversal algorithm, it should be some node whose printing step is already done. In this case, for the node 12, we see that the printing step of 12 is preceded immediately by a call to recursively print 12's left child. What is 12's left child? It is 10. Clearly 10 is the node that would be printed just before 12 in the Inorder traversal. Thus, 10 is the Inorder Predecessor of 12.

In general, it is easy to see that if a node has a left subtree, then the Inorder Precedessor for the node is the maximum node in it's left subtree.

But what if the node has no left subtree? Say, what is the Inorder Predecessor of the node 10? How do we find this?

Well, this is a bit tricky, as 10 does not have a left subtree. Let's think, which node could have been printed just before the node 10? We are looking for a node which has already been printed. First, how did we get to the node 10 in the traversal's algorithm sequence? We came left from the node 12, could the Inorder Predecessor be 12? No, because the node 12 would be only printed after 10, as per the algorithm, as 10 is being printed by the recursive call to the left subtree of node 12. Okay, what called 12? 8 called the recursive call to 12, as part of it's recursive call to it's right subtree. Okay, could 8 be the Inorder Predecessor? First have we printed 8 already? Yes, we have already printed 8 as we are now already in 8's right subtree. 8 is indeed the node that would be printed just before the node 10 in the Inorder Traversal. Why? What did we do just now? All we did was look back at how we ended up at node 10, retrace the steps and see the first node that has already been printed. Clearly, that is the Inorder Predecessor. Hence 8 is the Inorder Predecessor of 10.

In general, it is easy to see that if a node has no left subtree, all you need to do is go up the tree from your node to the root and in doing so, find the node which is a right child of it's parent, then the parent would be the Inorder Predecessor.

Thus, all you need to do to find a Inorder Predecessor of a node, is to trace back the recursive calls of how you got to the node in the traversal.

Summarizing:
 If the node has a left subtree, the Inorder Predecessor is the maximum key in the left subtree of the node.
 Else
  Go up till you find a node which is a right child of it's parent, then the parent would be the Inorder Predecessor.

Now, that we understand what an Inorder Predecessor is and how to figure it out in a BST, let's get back to our task. Since our node did not exist in the first place, then we would be inserting it(virtually atleast), which means it would be a leaf on insertion, which means it would have no left subtree, which means it's predecessor is in fact only up the tree. So, in one traversal, you should be able to do this task, without inserting actually.

Comment: Why is the parent of a right child the predecessor? Consider this example tree: [link](http://s9.postimg.org/qnag74zfj/tree_ex.jpg) and say you were searching for 15. In the search path you would go to 10, 20, 18, 14. If you were to insert 15 it would've been right of 14. Now in your algorithm if I understand correctly, we go up the path until we find a node with a right child, and that would be 20, while the predecessor is actually 14.

Comment: @OrelKanditan: The virtually inserted node is included in that "predecessor is the parent of a right child when you backtrack and go up the tree". Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but now say I want to find 13. The path would be the same, and it would virtually be inserted as a left son of 14. In this case the first node which is the parent of a right son up the path would be 20, and not 10 which is the predecessor.

Comment: @OrelKanditan: parent and son must be on the path that you are backtracking. 20 has a right child but that right child is not on the path that you are backtracking. If you continue going up, then 10 is the parent of 20 and 20 is the right child of 10, hence 10 is the predecessor.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, that part wasn't clear. This seems to work, although I'm not sure why

Comment: @OrelKanditan: Tried to explain, see if it helps you!

Comment: Great answer, thanks!